# MongoDB: Object of lists

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the following structure in my  MongoDB collection:

```
{
    item1{
        "foo1.py": ["hello1", "world1"],
        "bar1.py": ["hello2", "world2"],
        "baz1.py": ["hello3", "world3"]
    },
    item2{
        "foo2.py": ["hello1", "world1"],
        "bar2.py": ["hello2", "world2"],
        "baz2.py": ["hello3", "world3"]
    }
}
```

via Pymongo, I want to find in `item1` all lists that contain `1`. I should get `foo1 ["hello1", "world1"]`.

I tried this to test if a simple query works:
`db.collectionName.find({"item1.foo1.py": "1"})`
but it doesn't return anything.

How do I go about this?

Thank!

Comment: So you wanted to get `foo1.py` from `item1` field cause it has elements containing 1 in those ? Do you need to check all elements in an array should contain 1 or any one element is ok ?

Comment: Yes. Eventually I want to search the entire `item1` object and check for certain values. The query I tried should work though, not sure what my mistake is.

Comment: So you need to check each field in `item1` & also each element should contain `1` in each field's array ? Do you've to get this :: `"abc1.py": ["hello1", "world2"]`?

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: I think i know the issue, MongoDB does not allow "." character in the keys, so this is why I am not able to execute any queries.

Comment: Yes it makes it as sub-doc, So now is that working as expected ?

Comment: See [Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names): *Until support is added in the query language, the use of `$` and `.` in field names is not recommended and is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers.*

Comment: Yes, I am able to execute a single query. What if I want to search all the fields in `item1` for a certain value? do I use something like `createIndex` ?

Comment: @agukalpa : If you know the fields for sure & wanted to search on only those fields then you can create a compound index or multiple indexes which will help you to run queries fast enough !! But it you don't know keys in `item1` object & wanted to search values of keys of unknown then you need to use aggregate for that !!